# How do I change the "Indexed: Yes (No Duplicates)" constraint in Access to "Indexed: No" via SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access, constraints

I need to change a column in MS Access from indexed to non-indexed.

I need to do this via SQL because I do not have direct access to the database. I only have access to it via SQL.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [ANSI-92 Query Mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-ansi-sql-query-mode-mdb-HP003070483.aspx), a unique constraint is synonymous with a unique index, hence there are two syntaxes that both do the same thing:

```
ALTER TABLE TestMyIndex DROP
   CONSTRAINT uq__TestMyIndex__col1;

DROP INDEX uq__TestMyIndex__col1 
   ON TestMyIndex;
```

For a non-unique index, you must use `DROP INDEX`.